# How to execute a php variable into a python file when the variable has a space in it?

Tags: python, php

This is the line of code from the php file:

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec("python C:/xampp/htdocs/classiccars/selenium_test.py 'byu store'");
?>
```

This is the python file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

import sys

x = sys.argv[1]
print(x)

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/")

inputboxes = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'text_field')
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'searchboxinput').send_keys(x)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchbox-searchbutton")))
element.click()
```

The google chrome tab opens. Puts the url for google maps. Then puts 'byu into the search bar but doesn't include the whole type 'byu store'.

Comment: Might try `byu%20store` or `byu+store`.  If it come from a variable then `urlencode`.

Comment: The byu%20store didn't work but the byu+store showed the right result but ended up submitting 'byu+store' which I might have to settle for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wait for other answers, I don't really know Python.

Comment: Also, might ry `\"byu store\"` or `'\"byu store\"'` or something.

Comment: You don't give yourself enough credit I tried echo shell_exec("python C:/xampp/htdocs/classiccars/selenium_test.py '\"byu store\"'"); and it submitted 'byu store' which is exactly what I want. Thanks I really appreciate it!